# Sum squares of the sum of two columns for any amount of rows

Tags: excel

I am trying to calculate the sum of squares of the sum of two columns,
i.e.

```
 C1   C2
 a    b
 c    d
 Answer = (a+b)^2+(c+d)^2
```

I want this to all be in one equation and to generalise to any amount of rows, but it will always be just two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT()

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A3+B1:B3)^2)
```

[image]

---

To make the ranges dynamic use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))+$B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)))^2)
```

Now as the list grows or shrinks it will only look to the range with values.

Comment: This is perfect! I tried a couple of times with sumproduct but couldn't get the right answer

Comment: When the question is 15 minutes old you can mark this as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer, Please do that.